# How to validate a JSON object as an unordered list?

Tags: go

I have an endpoint written in Go. When you call it with a GET request it returns the following data on success (200):

```
{"Q":[{"A":"D","M":{"F":{"J":4,"K":3,"L":1}},"R":"S"},{"A":"E","M":{"F":{"J":4,"K":3,"L":1}},"R":"T"}]}
```

Now I'm trying to write a test-case that will check the return data from this endpoint and make sure it is as above. But the ordering of the two objects inside the list is irrelevant. IE if the second element comes first, the test-case should still pass.

How do I do it?

So far I am using `mapset`s from [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/deckarep/golang-set) to implement unordered lists in the test case like this:

```
 1  statusCode, bodyBytes, err := myHTTPRequestFunc(http.MethodGet, uri, headers, bytes.NewBuffer(body))
 2  assert.Nil(t, err)
 3  unmarshalledBody := make(map[string]interface{})
 4  err = json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &unmarshalledBody)
 5  assert.Nil(t, err)
 6  assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, statusCode)
 7  myList := unmarshalledBody["Q"].([]interface{})
 8  assert.Equal(t, 2, len(myList))
 9
10  expectedContexts := mapset.NewSet(). // mapset comes from here https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set
11  var jsonMap map[string](interface{})
12  var b []byte
13
14  jsonMap = make(map[string](interface{}))
15  b = []byte(`{"A":"D","M":{"F":{"J":4,"K":3,"L":1}},"R":"S"}`)
16  assert.Nil(t, json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &jsonMap))
17  expectedContexts.Add(jsonMap)
18
19  jsonMap = make(map[string](interface{}))
20  b = []byte(`{"A":"E","M":{"F":{"J":4,"K":3,"L":1}},"R":"T"}`)
21  assert.Nil(t, json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &jsonMap))
22  expectedContexts.Add(jsonMap)
23
24  receivedContexts := mapset.NewSet() // mapset comes from here https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set
25  receivedContexts.Add(myList[0])
26  receivedContexts.Add(myList[1])
27
28  assert.Equal(t, expectedContexts, receivedContexts)
```

But when I run this test case, I get the following error in line #17 when I try to add an item to the mapset:

```
panic: runtime error: hash of unhashable type map[string]interface {}
```

How can I add these items to the `mapset` properly?
Is there a better/easier/different approach to do this validation?

Comment: Looks like `mapset` is using the values you add to it as a map key. Maps, sllices cannot be used as map keys. If all you need is to compare two maps, you can use `reflect.DeepEqual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) function to compare the unmarshalled body interface with an expected result of your choice

Assuming you have the `unmarshalledBody` already available, form the interface from your expected result to compare it with

```
expected := `{"Q":[{"A":"D","M":{"F":{"J":4,"K":3,"L":1}},"R":"S"},{"A":"E","M":{"F":{"J":4,"K":3,"L":1}},"R":"T"}]}`
expectedBody := make(map[string]interface{})
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(expected), &expectedBody); err != nil {
    return
}   

result := reflect.DeepEqual(unmarshalledBody, expectedBody)
```

The comparison function returns a boolean depending on the outcome of the match. You can assert it if it returns true.

[Go playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/8x9RnRL5SdG)